# ASP.NET MVC routing add special convention mysitye/string

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am new to ASP.NET MVC. I have a web page with default routing:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
}
```

I have been working on developing an URL shortener that creates 5 character strings in base 32 (A-Z 0-9). My idea is to have the default routing in ASP.NET MVC and add a special case for

```
// this is the random code generated by my application
www.mypage.com/ASD12
```

How can I add this exception to my routing and always make URLs (`mypage.test/code`) land on a specific controller action?

```
public class CodeController : Controller
{
     public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string code)
     {
         //do things here
     }
}
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

After searching more,

```
          routes.MapRoute(
    name: "specialConvention",
    url: "{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "code", action = "Index" }
    );
```

That is the code I was looking for.